# byte[] toString() gives a weird string instead of actual value

Tags: java, android, string, byte

`byte[] a`  has value of {119}, which is the ascii equivalent of "w", but when I use `.toString()` to convert it to string, it gives me a weird string. any idea what I did wrong?

[image: simple image description]

```
byte[] a = characteristicRX.getValue();
        String rscvString = a.toString();
        Log.d("byteToHex", "rscvString = " + rscvString);
        while ( rscvString != "w" ){
```

Comment: Check the required encoding and parametrize as required with the `new String(a, someEncoding)` idiom. **Edit** actually you are invoking `toString` on an array, so what is getting printed is the object type and hash. The above is still valid.

Comment: Check that warning you're getting, it's probably saying the same thing.

Comment: String s = new String(a);

Comment: thanks guys! its working now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String object takes a parameter of `byte[]` as an overloaded constructor. Use `String rscvString = new String(a);` and you should be sorted

You can't use boolean operators to test against strings ie. != or ==. 
use `while ( !(rscvString.equalsIgnoreCase("w") )` the `equalsIgnoreCase()` method will return a boolean and the ! will force the test against the false.

Comment: thanks! the string has the correct value now! rscvString is now "w", 
but somehow, the program still goes into the
while(rscvString != "w") loop.. any idea whats wrong this time?

Comment: You can't use `boolean` operators to test against strings ie. `!=` or `==`. use `while ( !(rscvString.equalsIgnoreCase("w") )` the `equalsIgnoreCase()` method will return a `boolean` and the ! will force the test against the false.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the `equals()` can also be used, but this will cause it to be case sensitive. Testing with `boolean` operators compare the memory locations and not the values.

Comment: Thanks! its working as it should now :)
edited so both answers are together. 
thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the lines below to cast a byte to a character and transform it to String

```
String rscvString = String.valueOf((char) a);
String rscvString = String.valueOf((char) (a & 0xFF));
```

You can pass a byte array in the String constructor to get a String object of your array.